# How to query in string fields in Solr

Tags: solr

I've this problem. My query is like this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:EV11777-01 AND DocType:LLP AND PackName:06 Delivery Documents - MiniPack
```

The fields(strSO,PackName,DocType) type is **string**. The fields type was **text_general** at first. But I have to make them **string**. Before changing the field types query was working correctly. But when I'm doing it **string** query response gives me nothing. What's wrong at here?
Here my query response

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"strSO:EV11777-01 AND DocType:LLP AND PackName:06 Delivery Documents - MiniPack"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong at here?

That depends on you field-content.
Keep in mind, that fields with type = string are not tokenized!

See the solr docs: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/field-types-included-with-solr.html  (Class StrField)

> String (UTF-8 encoded string or Unicode). Strings are intended for small fields and are not tokenized or analyzed in any way. They have a hard limit of slightly less than 32K.

So your query will match an field, only if the field content matches exactly the query content.

For example field content `ABC  DE` will not match an query like `ABC DE` (one space is missing between the letters at the query)

I recommend using the solr analysis feature from the solr admin page to see, how solr processes your query. You will find this feature at an url like this: http://:8983/solr/#//analysis

Comment: Okey, I understand and I solved it. I use `copyField`  method and it worked. Thank you for your advice.