# solr string field getting no results

Tags: solr, lucene, pylucene, pysolr

I have indexed some data using the string field for `name` and the entries look like so on my index:

```
  {
    "custom_id":"234323244323242",
    "full_id":"ju7328732",
    "weblink":"https://planet.org/323232",
    "name":"idexlab",
    "type":"entry",
    "id":"151e0151-1036-4b97-86d1-59f8adaeb8a7",
    "_version_":1770751587544727552},
```

I created the schema by passing this:

```
    ( curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"name", "type":"string", "multiValued":false, "stored":true, "indexed":true, "termVectors":true }}' "http://localhost:8984/solr/$core_name/schema" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print('***adding name:', json.load(sys.stdin)['responseHeader']['status'])" );
```

Now, when I search for `idexlab` on the gui I get nothing :(
why? the equivalent query code is:

```
http://localhost:8984/solr/#/final_idx/query?q=idexlab&q.op=OR&indent=true&useParams=
```

The same works fine when I set the field to `text_general`.
My understanding was that the `string` type can be used for exact match cases.

So, why wouldnt this work?

Comment: nvm.. I fixed it using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144118/how-to-query-in-string-fields-in-solr turns out I needed a copyfield with _text_.. bit bizzare but works

Comment: Exact matches on string fields work in Solr, they must be really exact (including spaces and case matching) but they work. I don't see a field indicated in your query, I would have expected your `q` parameter to look like `q=name:idexlab` or that you specify `name` as a search fields somehow (e.g. via the `qf` parameter or via a setting in your Solr config)